# Empty constructor for an ExpandoObject?

Tags: c#, json, expandoobject

Is it possible to dynamically add an empty constructor to an ExpandoObject? The reason I want to do this is because I'm using JSON.Net library and it seems to need an empty constructor in order to convert a Json Object into a .NET Object.

I've been following [this guide](https://www.oreilly.com/learning/building-c-objects-dynamically) to learn how to dynamically add properties to the ExpandoObject. It also specifies how to add methods and events, but I'm not sure how to add an empty constructor, so that JSON.Net could use it to buid a .Net Object.

This is the code I've written so far:

```
private static void ExpandoTest( Program oProgram )
{
    dynamic oResponse = new ExpandoObject();

    // Add a Constructor
    // ---->>>>>>   HOW TO DO THIS?

    // Dynamically added properties
    AddProperty( oResponse, "success", false );
    AddProperty( oResponse, "nRows", 0 );
    List<Dictionary<string, string>> aResult = GenerateResultsList();
    AddProperty( oResponse, "aResult", aResult );

    // .NET to JSON
    string cExpandoJson = JSONHandler.Serialize( oResponse );

    // JSON to .NET
    // Json.Net needs an empty to constructor of oResponse to do this.

    Debug.WriteLine( "" );
}

// Adds a new property to an ExpandoObject object.
public static void AddProperty( ExpandoObject oObj, string propertyName, object propertyValue )
{
    IDictionary<string, object> oExpandoDict = oObj as IDictionary<string, object>;

    if((oExpandoDict.ContainsKey( propertyName )))
        oExpandoDict[propertyName] = propertyValue;
    else
        oExpandoDict.Add( propertyName, propertyValue );
}


// Converts the .NET object to a JSON string.
public static string Serialize( object oNetObject )
{
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject( oNetObject );
}
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Json.NET has builtin support for `ExpandoObject` via [`ExpandoObjectConverter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Converters_ExpandoObjectConverter.htm).  Since it's built-in it's used automatically and there's no need to add it to serializer settings.  Also, what do you mean by *add an empty constructor*?  `ExpandoObject` already has an [empty constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.expandoobject(v=vs.110).aspx), you are calling it in your code already.

Comment: *" it seems to need an empty constructor in order to convert a Json Object into a .NET Object"* - do you get an error? Which one and at which statement?

Comment: JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<oResponse>(cExpandoJson); it is needed a constructor for the oResponse type; I guess Json.Net needs the oResponse properties in order to make a proper conversion.

Comment: @dbc By "empty constructor" I mean the equivalent to: public Response() {}, but dynamically added to the ExpandoObject named oResponse. Thanks.